# Erlang drop messages

Tags: erlang, message

I have a proxy that prevents the server from getting overloaded with requests.
Clients sends their requests to the proxy and the proxy determine wether or not to pass the requests to the server.

NrOfReq is the current number of requests that the server is handling.
MaxReq is the maximum number of requests that the server can handle before
the mailbox get full.

Every time the server has handled a request it sends the ready_to_serve atom
to the proxy.

Whenever the guard after the when-keyword is false I want to drop the message from the client and prevent it from ending up in the proxys mail-box.
How can I do this?

```
proxy(ServerPid, NrOfReq, MaxReq) ->
    receive
            {client_request, Request, ClientPid} when NrOfReq < MaxReq ->
                    New = NrOfReq + 1,
                    ServerPid ! {Request, ClientPid, self()};
            ready_to_serve ->
                    New = NrOfReq - 1
    end,
    proxy(ServerPid, New, MaxReq).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Separate message receiving from message handling

   ```
   proxy(ServerPid, NrOfReq, MaxReq) ->
       receive
           {client_request, Request, ClientPid} ->
                   if 
                       NrOfReq < MaxReq ->
                           New = NrOfReq + 1,
                           ServerPid ! {Request, ClientPid, self()};
                       true ->
                           'message-dropped';
                   end;
           ready_to_serve ->
                   New = NrOfReq - 1
   end,
   proxy(ServerPid, New, MaxReq).
   ```
2. Or else make fallback clause for dropping messages

   ```
   proxy(ServerPid, NrOfReq, MaxReq) ->
       receive
           {client_request, Request, ClientPid} when NrOfReq < MaxReq ->
               New = NrOfReq + 1,
               ServerPid ! {Request, ClientPid, self()};
           {client_request, Request, ClientPid} when NrOfReq >= MaxReq  ->
               'message-dropped';
           ready_to_serve ->
               New = NrOfReq - 1
   end,
   proxy(ServerPid, New, MaxReq).
   ```

The latter is a bit flatter but can cause issues when you decide to change message format.

PS: *Why you no use OTP?*

Answer (score 0):

I never tried your proposal, on my side I would use 2 clauses for the loop:

```
proxy(ServerPid, MaxReq, MaxReq) ->
    receive
            ready_to_serve ->
                    New = NrOfReq - 1
    end,
    proxy(ServerPid, New, MaxReq);

proxy(ServerPid, NrOfReq, MaxReq) ->
    receive
        {client_request, Request, ClientPid} ->
                New = NrOfReq + 1,
                ServerPid ! {Request, ClientPid, self()};
        ready_to_serve ->
                New = NrOfReq - 1
    end,
    proxy(ServerPid, New, MaxReq).
```

This proxy looks weird to me. The pattern I saw most often in Erlang is to spawn 1 server per client, and have dedicated processes to spawn those servers, manage storage ...

Comment: "This proxy looks weird to me."  Yes that might be the best way to do it but I thought that messages also could be dropped/deleted?(in this case if  `NrOfReq >= MaxReq`)

Comment: Using a proxy to drop messages makes sense if there is a risk of overload. It will allow you to drop the last incoming messages and avoid the saturation of the mailbox. In this case, the pattern 1 server per client should also take care of this (limit the number of client?). Note that a server is essentially a loop, so you can include the filtering in the loop itself, even using a gen_server.